# How to debug tungsten-replicator step by step?

Tags: debugging, tungsten-replicator

I want to understand how `tungsten-replicator` works, so I want to debug it using *Eclipse* or *JIDEA*. But I have no idea how to start it, any idea is appreciate.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: @KarlRichter   I import the tungsten-replicator project( I download it from [link](https://github.com/shutterstock/tungsten-replicator) )  into workspace ,and I install it by tpm command and run the server in two hosts (master and slave) to replicate the data from mysql to mongodb. I'm interested in how it works so I want to debug it step by step .So I think there maybe some ways to attach the process like VS.

Comment: You're close to an answerable question (maybe edit rather than posting comments because people won't bother reading comments). This is platform on programming questions and question are expected to show research effort (things you tried and detailed explanation about the expected and actual behaviour). I'm voting to close this until you make the necessary improvements. See http://stackoverflow.com/help for support.